# Sbt testOnly from Windows console

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

If I type *sbt* and then enter *testOnly packagename.**, it's work fine.
But if I type *sbt "testOnly packagename.**" in windows console, it's just enter sbt console.
So how can I ran specific tests from cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

The correct commando here is `test-only`:

```
sbt "test-only packagename.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is really an answer, but I am not allowed to make comments yet. It might be an `issue` with `sbt`, (I did not find it listed currently), but it could be a problem with the way the windows command prompt "shell" processes wildcards. If you need this functionality from the command prompt window, you might find workarounds [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows%20command%20prompt%20wildcard%20expansion).

Another workaround: the command with wildcards, `sbt "testOnly packagename.*"` will work when executed from the "bash" shell that is provided by [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bug in sbt that has a fix waiting https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/122